# Form Validation Issues Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, prompt

I'm trying to get my HTML & Javascript code to generate a similar prompt (see image below something similar in principle). Instead of the prompt working a page called "HTML - Form Data Extraction Test" comes up instead.

Struggling to pin point where I'd gone wrong as my labels and ID's are in place, I've been using "getelementbyid", defined all the instances of when the messages should appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
/* function validate()will validate form data */
function validate() {
  var jref = document.getElementById("jref").value;
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var genm = document.getElementById("genm").checked;
  var genf = document.getElementById("genf").checked;
  var saddress = document.getElementById("saddress").value;
  var stown = document.getElementById("stown").value;
  var pnumber = document.getElementById("pnumber").value;

  //NEED LABELS FOR
  //state dropdown
  //Skills drop down

  var errMsg = "";
  var result = true; /* assumes no errors */
  //var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;                   /* regular expression for letters and spaces only */

  if (jref == "") {
    errMsg += "Job Reference Number cannot be Empty\n";
    //errMsg = errMsg + "First Name cannot be 
  }

  if (fname == "") {
    errMsg += "First Name cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if (lname == "") {
    errMsg += "Last Name cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if (dob == "") {
    errMsg += "Date of Birth cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if (email == "") {
    errMsg += "Email cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if ((genm == "") && (genf == "")) { //check whether gender is selected
    errMsg += "A gender must be selected.\n";
  }

  if (saddress == "") {
    errMsg += "Street Address cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if (stown == "") {
    errMsg += "Suburb or Town cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if (pnumber == "") {
    errMsg += "Phone Number cannot be Empty\n";
  }

  if (errMsg != "") {
    alert(errMsg);
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}

function init() {
  /* assign the <form> element to variable regForm */
  var appForm = document.getElementById("appForm");

  /* link function validate() to the onsubmit event of the form */
  appForm.onsubmit = validate;
}

/* execute function init() once the window is loaded*/
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<main>

  <!-- Start of the form that the user fills out -->
  <form method="post" action="http://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" id="appForm">
    <h1>Job Application Form</h1>

    <label for="jref">Job Reference Number</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="jref" maxlength="5" id="jref" pattern="\d{4}" /><br>

    <fieldset>
      <label for="fname">First Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" maxlength="20" name="fname" /> <br>

      <label for="lname">Last Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" maxlength="20" name="lname" /><br>

      <label for="dob">Date of birth:</label><br>
      <input id="dob" type="date" name="dob" /><br>

      <label>Gender</label>
      <input id="genm" type="radio" name="genm" value="Male" />
      <label for="genm">Male</label>
      <input id="genf" type="radio" name="genf" value="Female" />
      <label for="genf">Female</label><br>

      <label for="saddress">Street Address</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="saddress" maxlength="40" name="saddress" /><br>

      <label for="stown">Suburb/Town</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="stown" maxlength="40" name="stown" /><br> State

      <br>
      <select name="slRank">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="8">ACT</option>
        <option value="8">ACT</option>
        <option value="7">TAS</option>
        <option value="6">SA</option>
        <option value="5">WA</option>
        <option value="4">NT</option>
        <option value="3">QLD</option>
        <option value="2">NSW</option>
        <option value="1">VIC</option>
      </select><br>

      <label for="email">Email Address</label><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" /><br>

      <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label><br>
      <input type="tel" id="pnumber" name="pnumber" placeholder="(##) ####-####" /><br> Skills
      <select name="slRank">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="9">Creativity</option>
        <option value="8">Interpersonal Skills</option>
        <option value="7">Critical Thinking</option>
        <option value="6">Problem Solving</option>
        <option value="5">Public Speaking</option>
        <option value="4">Communication</option>
        <option value="3">Collaboration</option>
        <option value="2">Accounting</option>
        <option value="1">Other</option>
      </select><br /><br />

      <label>Other Skills</label>
      <br />
      <textarea autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Please fill out other skills you have here."></textarea><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: I put your code in a JSFiddle. Other then your phone number validation has some contradiction in it (the pattern requires 17 characters but maxLength is 12), validation seems to work fine. The Messagebox you show cannot originate from the posted code because there is no message *"User ID cannot be empty"* in your code. Maybe you have an old version in the brwoser cache?

Answer (score 0):

user this https://jqueryvalidation.org/ js library for form validation